# Sending raw binary data as a HttpParam with Angular HttpClient

Tags: angular, httpclient

I'm trying to send browser input file as one of the HttpParams but not as [object File] I need it to be raw binary (binary) with application/octet-stream type.
Second param should be string.
Example:

```
sendFile(options):Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
  let prms = new HttpParams();
  prms = prms.append('file', options.file);
  prms = prms.append('format', options.format);
  return this.http.post(url,prms,{
    observe: 'response'
  }).map(data => {
    return data;
  },error => Observable.throw(error))
}
```

Anyone have idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From Angular 5 onwards, in HttpParams one can only have string as value. So for first param you will have to convert it to string. To convert it to string, follow this [Link](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/380/how-to-convert-a-binary-string-into-a-readable-string-and-vice-versa-with-javascript)

Comment: Yeah that's not gonna work I can read File as string with FileReader API but Rest API on server expects binary

Answer (score 0):

Ok for someone scratching their head with similar issue you just have to use FormData instead of HttpParams:

```
sendFile(options):Observable<HttpResponse<any>>{
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('importFile', options.file);
   formData.append('format', options.format);
   return this.http.post(url,formData,{
     observe: 'response'
   }).map(data => {
     return data;
   },error => Observable.throw(error))
}
```